# Using CF_SWIFT_NAME to import a C struct getter and setter that bridges to Foundation from Core Foundation

Tags: swift, objective-c, foundation, core-foundation, toll-free-bridging

I have a struct, `House`, that I want usable in both Objective-C and in Swift (additionally, I just wanted to test the bounds of what I could and couldn't import from C to Swift).

`House` is defined as follows:

```objectivec
typedef struct {
    NSUInteger number;
    CFStringRef street CF_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
    CFStringref city CF_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
    StateCode stateCode; // an enum, whose definition isn't relevant to this question 
    NSUInteger zip;
} House;
```

To avoid using `Unmanaged<T>` in Swift,  `street` and `city` each have accessor methods that bridge the underlying `CFStringRef` to `NSString*`. The accessors for `city` are practically identical, so I'll omit them here and only provide the accessors for `street`.

House.h

```objectivec
NSString* HouseGetStreet(const House* h) CF_SWIFT_NAME(getter:House.street(self:));
void HouseSetStreet(House* h, NSString* newStreet) CF_SWIFT_NAME(setter:House.street(self:newStreet:));
```

House.m

```objectivec
NSString* HouseGetStreet(const House* h) {
    return [(__bridge NSString*)h->street copy];
}

void HouseSetStreet(House* h, NSString* newStreet) {
    CFStringRef* currentStreet = &h->street;
    CFStringRef street2 = (__bridge CFStringRef)street; // don't retain yet

        if (*currentStreet != street2) {
            CFRelease(*currentStreet);
            *currentStreet = CFRetain(street2); // now we retain
        } else {
            return;
    }
}
```

When defining only the getter method, Swift imports the `street` property as a `Swift.String` and everything works fine. But when I define the setter methods, Swift acts like the `street` property doesn't even exist and I can't get or set the field from Swift code.